# I want to zoom in and out my browser using webdriverio can anyone help on this

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io, webdriver-io-v4

This code is not working for me

```
describe("Zoom in and zoom out using keyboard", function () {
  it("Should open the application main page ", async function () {
    await browser.url("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/key_presses");
    await browser.keys(["Control", "-"]);
    await browser.keys(["Control", "-"]);
    // await browser.keys('Control')
    // await browser.keys('-');
    //  await browser.keys('Control')
    //await browser.keys('-');
    await browser.maximizeWindow();
    const search = $("//input[@id='target']");
    await search.click();
    await browser.pause(5000);
    await browser.saveScreenshot("./screenshots/keypress.png");
    //browser.pause(5000)
  });
});
```

Can any one give my the correct code

Answer (score 1):

```
await browser.execute(() => {

    document.body.style.zoom = `70%`; // Adjust the percentage as per your requirement

  });
```